# Loop json Output in shell script

Tags: bash, jq

I have this output variable

```
OUTPUT=$(echo $ZONE_LIST  | jq -r '.response | .data[]')
```

The Output:

```
{
  "accountId": "xyz",
  "addDate": "2020-09-05T10:57:11Z",
  "content": "\"MyContent\"",
  "id": "MyID",
  "priority": null
}
{
  "accountId": "xyz",
  "addDate": "2020-09-05T06:58:52Z",
  "content": "\"MyContent\"",
  "id": "MyID",
  "priority": null
}
```

How can I create a loop for this two values?

```
MyLoop
  echo "$content - $id"
done
```

I tried this, but then I get a loop through every single value

```
for k in $(echo $ZONE_LIST  | jq -r '.response | .data[]'); do
    echo $k
done
```

EDIT 1:

```
My complete JSON:

{
    "errors": [],
    "metadata": {
        "transactionId": "",
    },
    "response": {
        "data": [
            {
                "accountId": "xyz",
                "addDate": "2020-09-05T10:57:11Z",
                "content": "\"abcd\"",
                "id": "myID1",
                "lastChangeDate": "2020-09-05T10:57:11Z",
            },
            {
                "accountId": "xyz",
                "addDate": "2020-09-05T06:58:52Z",
                "content": "\"abc\"",
                "id": "myID2",
                "lastChangeDate": "2020-09-05T07:08:15Z",
            }
        ],
        "limit": 10,
        "page": 1,
        "totalEntries": 2,
    },
    "status": "success",
    "warnings": []
}
```

Now I need a loop for data, because I need it for a curl

The curl NOW:

```
curl -s -v -X POST --data '{
    "deleteEntries": [
        Data_from_json
    ]
}' https://URL_to_Update 2>/dev/null)
```

Now I want to create a new variable from my JSON data. My CURL should look like this at the end:

```
curl -s -v -X POST --data '{
    "deleteEntries": [
        {
            "readID": "myID1",
            "date": "2020-09-05T10:57:11Z", <--Value from addDate
            "content": "abcd"
        },
        {
            "readID": "myID2",
            "date": "2020-09-05T06:58:52Z", <--Value from addDate
            "content": "abc"
        }
    ]
}' https://URL_to_Update 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Add content of `$ZONE_LIST` to your question.

Comment: As your purpose is to extract data from json then format them back to json, IMO it would be much better to avoid the shell loop and use jq to directly generate the final json. For example `postdata=$(jq '.response.data | { deleteEntries: map({ readID: .id, date: .addDate, content: (.content | fromjson) }) }' <<<"$ZONE_LIST")` then simply `curl -s -v -X POST --data "$postdata" https://URL_to_Update 2>/dev/null`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
for k in $(echo $ZONE_LIST  | jq -rc '.response | .data[]'); do
    echo $k|jq '.content + " - " + .id' -r
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS=$'\37' read -r -d '' id content; do
  echo "$id" "$content"
done < <(
  jq -j '.response | .data[] | .id + "\u001f" + .content + "\u0000"' \
  <<<"$ZONE_LIST"
)
```

- `jq -j`: Forces a raw output from `jq`.
- `.id + "\u001f" + .content + "\u0000"`: Assemble fields delimited by ASCII FS (Hexadecimal `1f` or Octal `37`), and end record by a `null` character.

It then becomes easy and reliable to iterate over `null` delimited records by having `read -d ''` (`null` delimiter).

Fields `id` `content` are separated by ASCII FS, so just set the **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator `IFS` environment variable to the corresponding octal `IFS=$'37'` before reading.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to realize you can turn the set of fields into an array like this using a technique like this:

```
jq '(.accountId + "," + .addDate)'
```

Now you can update your bash loop:

```sh
for k in $(echo $ZONE_LIST  | jq -r '.response | .data[]' | jq '(.content + "," + .id)'); do
    echo $k
done
```

There is probably a way to combine the two `jq` commands but I don't have your original `json` data for testing.

**UPDATE** - inside the loop you can parse the comma-delimited string into separate fields. This are more efficient ways to handle this task but I prefer simplicity.

```
    ID=$(echo $k | cut -d',' -f1)
    PRIORITY=$(echo $k | cut -d',' -f2)
    echo "ID($ID)  PRIORITY($PRIORITY)"
```

Comment: Thanks. the problem is that I need the values separately because I need it for another CURL call. I am editing the first post. Please give me 2 minutes